# UserModel is not assignable to parameter of type Document | nulll [mongoose with Typescript]

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

Typescript gives me an error. The error is due to the fact that mongoose expects that the promise of a search will resolve with a mongoose document (in this case the document of the user) or "null".
 But I want to access all the user's methods, so I have to specify that that function will take the user's model as an argument. But this thing causes me the following error:

Argument of type '(user: UserModel) => Response' is not assignable to parameter of type '(res: Document | null) => void | Response | PromiseLike'.

This is the code:

```
    import express, { Request, Response } from "express";


   import User, { UserModel } from "../../models/User";
    // router
    const router = express.Router();

    // @route   GET api/user/username/:username
    // @access  Public

    router.get("/username/:username", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      User.findOne({ username: req.params.username })
        .then((user: UserModel | null) => res.json(user))
        .catch(err => res.json(err));
    });

    export default router;
```

This is the user's model:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

export type UserModel = mongoose.Document & {
  name: string; 
  username: string;
  email: string; 
  password: string; 
  avatar: string;
  created_at: Date; 
};


export const UserSchema = new Schema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },

  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  avatar: {
    type: String
  },

  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

export default model("User", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `model` function accepts a type argument for the document type of the collection.  (It's trusting you; it doesn't have any way to verify that the type is correct.)  Replace:

```
export default model("User", UserSchema);
```

with:

```
export default model<UserModel>("User", UserSchema);
```

Then all queries on this collection will produce `UserModel` objects.

Comment: Hi @Matt McCutchen, I tried to do what he told me but tells me that the type 'Model <Document>' can not be converted into 'UserModel' type.

Comment: Check that you inserted `<UserModel>` after `model` (as a type argument), not before it (as a type assertion).

Comment: Thank you so much @Matt McCutchen, you made me discover a new thing that surely from now I will always use, but only now I could verify that vscode still complains about the fact that the promise can be resolved with the UserModel or null so says it is wrong to assign the UserModel type to the result of the promise.

Comment: Are you getting the error with the code in the question, with the callback written as `(user: UserModel | null) => res.json(user)`?  If so, it doesn't give me an error, so please publish a repository that reproduces the problem so I can see your whole configuration.  On the other hand, if you wrote the callback as `(user: UserModel) => ...`, then an error is expected: since `null` is a possible result of `findOne`, you have to declare it and then check for it at runtime (which should automatically narrow the type of `user` to `UserModel`), or else disable `strictNullChecks`.

Comment: Sorry if I still trouble you @Matt McCutchen, I tried to do what you told me and you absolutely right, but at this point now I wonder why using the callback instead of the promise I can simply define `(user: UserModel | null)` instead of `(user: UserModel)`, even if it is explicitly stated that the callback pass null or Usermodel. Even in the  [official repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/master/src/controllers/user.ts)  it is declareted  `(user: UserModel)`instead of  `(user: UserModel | null)`

Comment: The mongoose declarations look consistent to me between the callback and promise APIs.  With `strictNullChecks` enabled, both should give you an error if you don't include `null` in the type.  The starter repository you linked is old and has `strictNullChecks` disabled, so code there will be able to treat the `null` type as if it didn't exist.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience